# Convert data into JSON and send it to REST Server

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, rest

My REST Server registration model schema is :

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "mobile": "string",
  "accType": "string",
  "meta": "string",
  "createdAt": 0
}
```

I'm registering an user. The jquery ajax request is :

```
function signin_email() {

    var em = $('#lg_email').val();
    var ps = $('#lg_password').val();

    var user_login = {
        action: "user_login",
        email: em,
        password: ps
    };

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>home/signin_email_sp",
        data: user_login,
        cache: false,
        success: function(r) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(r);

            if (obj.log_code == 1) {
                $('#login_alert').text("Success").show();
            } else {
                $('#login_alert').text("Failed").show();
            }
        },
    });
}
```

On the server side, what I'm doing is simply going for `$_POST`

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

How can I convert the whole into a JSON data and pass to my model so that it can do the post to the service? This thing I have to do in my Controller.

And is it necessary to use `dataType : json` in jquery. If so, then which will be a better approach?

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)

Comment: `dataType: json` just tells jQuery to call `JSON.parse(r)` for you.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a JSON formatted request with JavaScript or a JSON formatted request from PHP? Or are you asking how to make a JSON formatted response from PHP?

Comment: @Quentin : Which one is going to be better? From Javascript or from Php? Why and how?

Comment: @SamirReddy — None of them are going to be "better", just different, and suited for different things. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Quentin Can you be more specific about "different things"? I have mentioned everything in the question itself.

Comment: @SamirReddy — One is when the browser talks to your server. One is when your server talks to another server. One is when your server responds to the browser.